# Android - items in submenu do not appear when clicking on parent menu

Tags: android, menu, android-emulator, submenu, nexus-one

Please..please help!
I'm new with android development. After i create an app with simple menu. i click on the parent menu, i don't see the items in the submenu appeared. I don't know why is that. Enyone know this, please teach me.

i use nexus Emulator to show result. (nesux S (4.0", 480 X 800:ddpi)

create menu in the Menu folder -> menu-demo like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/addnew" android:title="add new">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/name" android:title="add  name"></item>
            <item android:id="@+id/age" android:title="Add age"></item>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/update" android:title="update"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/delete" android:title="delete"></item>
</menu>
```

i update Mainactivity.java in the src.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_demo, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `android:showAsAction="[property"`.
You can use a few parameters for `showAsAction`, such as `always`, `never`, and `ifRoom`.

Add these properties to your code, so for example, a menu item that I always want to appear on the actionbar would be like

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="test" >
</item
```

For submenus, you basically want the topmost selection shown as an action `always` and the submenu shown `never`.